# Unity services error : "You are not authorized to set the license key"

Tags: unity-game-engine, license-key

I was trying to implement IAP to my game and I went to Google Play Console and copeid my license key from there. And I pasted it to my Unity Dashboard and Unity key verify. However it gives error like : "You are not authorized to set the license key".

**Solution tried :**
Tried to enable the Legacy Analytics but I don't have this because it is deprecated now in my version.

What to do now?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by doing nothing. I just copied the id from the google play store and pasted it to my Unity Dashboard. There is no need to paste it to Unity game from project settings. I bought my in app product and it is completely working. I got the money and revenue too.